# C# Select query not modifying external variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with n elements, and a property that returns the root sum square of the elements:

```
public double Length 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        double sum = 0.0; 
        Elements.Select(t => sum += t * t);  
        return Math.Sqrt(sum); 
    } 
}
```

However, that doesn't work - no matter the value of the elements, sum remains 0.0.
Why doesn't this work?

Note: I have already implemented it another way, but am looking to understand why the above code does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ uses [deferred execution](http://www.develop-one.net/blog/2008/05/02/C30DeferredExecution.aspx) – the [Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) doesn't execute the lambda for all elements immediately, but returns an [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) which, when executed, performes the lambda on each element as it's enumerated.

Also note that LINQ is for querying, not for executing a block of code for each element. You should write your code such that there is no statement in the lambda, only a  expression that is free of side-effects. You can use the [Sum Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734) when you're trying to calculate a sum:

```
public double Length 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        double sum = elements.Select(t => t * t).Sum();
        return Math.Sqrt(sum); 
    } 
}
```

or

```
public double Length 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        double sum = elements.Sum(t => t * t);
        return Math.Sqrt(sum); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that because the specified code does not have any subsequent enumeration on the Selected items, the expression is never evaluated, and sum will not be changed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And you shouldn't enumerate the selected items just so the lambda is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Deferred execution.

Try this:

```
public double Length
{
    get { return Math.Sqrt(Elements.Sum(t => t * t)); }
}
```

Here the linq query is executed immediately.

Comment: This is in fact the solution I have implemented, but does not answer what it was about the other method that makes it not work as I expected.

Comment: I should elaborate.  The Select statement returns an IEnumerable<T>, which is created once the IEnumerable is iterated.  Since you are never iterating over the IEnumerable, the query is never performed.  Hence sum is not modified.

Comment: @3Pi: It answers precisely why your other method doesn't work: Look up deferred execution

Answer (score 0):

This don't work because Deferred Execution.
You can read this

[LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

[Understanding LINQ's Deferred Execution](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_linq/article.php/c16935/Understanding-LINQs-Deferred-Execution.htm)